# Can we do Print from the Windows Application in C# with separate thread?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, printing

I have an application which uses Print functionality. 
I have used separate thread to print a document i.e. convert it to XPS by sending Print to Microsoft XPS Document Writer.

I have tried to Print multiple documents in separate thread as well as in main UI thread. But while Printing in background, the application gets crashed and Event Viewer shows access permission issue.

When I tried to do Print multiple documents in main thread i.e. UI thread, then application shows "Print" dialog.

I want to Print document silently without any Print Dialog.

My code works perfectly when I build it in Debug mode, But it shows Print Dialog when I build it in Release mode.

Thank you.

Comment: `My code works perfectly fine` so whats the code?

Comment: @sLw It is printing documents silently when I build application in Debug mode.
But it shows Print Dialog when I build application in Release Mode.
I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

> I have used separate thread to print a document

I didn't see your code, but generally, can be used a Task for separates tasks in your app

for Example:

```
var tasks1 = Task.Run(() => { PrintDoc(); });
```

> But while Printing in background, the application gets crashed

maybe it depends on the vareble of the other thread or It requires printing a file that is not yet available or is being used elsewhere

> I want to Print document silently without any Print Dialog.

you need to use PrintController befor printing the document

```
doc.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
```